# Not able to csv read file correctly in pyspark dataframe because of quotes

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file in HDFS and I am reading it from pyspark but in 1 columns we have column values with quotes because of that other columns are  getting  null value.

```
df= spark.read.csv("hdfs://ip-10-0-0-178.ec2.internal:8020/user/root/etl_project/part-m-00000", header = False, schema = fileSchema,escape="\"")
```

It is reading as :

| year | month | day | weekday | hour | atm_status | atm_id | atm_manufacturer | atm_location | atm_streetname | atm_street_number | atm_zipcode | atm_lat | atm_lon | currency | card_type | service | message_code | message_text | weather_lat | weather_lon | weather_city_id | weather_city_name | temp | pressure | humidity | wind_speed | wind_deg | rain_3h | clouds_all | weather_id | weather_main | weather_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | January | 1 | Sunday | 9 | Active | 41 | Diebold Nixdorf | Skagen | Sct. Laurentiivej | 36 | 9990 | 57.7226197 | 10.5900563 | DKK | Mastercard - on-us | Withdrawal | 4014 | 'Suspected malfunction,0.000,57.721,11,2613939,0.000,277,1005,75,3,290.000,0,80,803,Clouds' | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |

desired output

| year | month | day | weekday | hour | atm_status | atm_id | atm_manufacturer | atm_location | atm_streetname | atm_street_number | atm_zipcode | atm_lat | atm_lon | currency | card_type | service | message_code | message_text | weather_lat | weather_lon | weather_city_id | weather_city_name | temp | pressure | humidity | wind_speed | wind_deg | rain_3h | clouds_all | weather_id | weather_main | weather_description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | January | 1 | Sunday | 9 | Active | 41 | Diebold Nixdorf | Skagen | Sct. Laurentiivej | 36 | 9990 | 57.7226197 | 10.5900563 | DKK | Mastercard - on-us | Withdrawal | 4014 | "Suspected malfunction" | 57.720928 | 10.58394 | 2613939 | Skagen | 277.41 | 1005 | 75 | 3 | 290 |  | 80 | 803 | Clouds | broken clouds |

How can i read file properly using pyspark dataframe for desired output.

Comment: What is the original data? This is really confusing.

Comment: can you share the sample of your input data?